# Testing form() with Phpunit in Symfony : InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test my application built in Symfony with PhpUnit (in local). In my homepage, I have a simple form to submit. I follow all the steps in various documentation (Symfony, phpUnit) and I've tested a lot of different solution from various forum but I'm still stuck...

Here is my test class :

```
namespace tests\FormBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class FormControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testReservationAction() 
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/tp4_louvres/web/app.php/info_reservation');

        $bouton = $crawler->selectButton('Valider');

        $form = $bouton->form(); //Here is the line 18 of the error

        $validationFormulaire = $client->submit($form, array(
            '#form_jour_jour' => '12/12/2017',
            '#form_nom_reservation' => 'Robert',
            '#form_prenom_reservation' => 'Paul',
            '#form_email' => 'paul.robert@gmail.com'
        ));

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/tp4_louvres/web/app.php/info_billet'));

    } // End of testReservationAction()


} // End class
```

and here is the form of my html page :

```
<form name="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required">Date de visite</label>
        <div id="form_jour" class="col-3 p-0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="form_jour_jour" name="form[jour][jour]" required="required" class="datepicker form-control" readonly="readonly" value="14/12/2017" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="form_nom_reservation">Nom de la réservation</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_nom_reservation" name="form[nom_reservation]" required="required" class="form-control" value="FIACRE" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="form_prenom_reservation">Prénom de la réservation</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_prenom_reservation" name="form[prenom_reservation]" required="required" class="form-control" value="Thibault" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="form_email">Email de la réservation</label>
        <input type="email" id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" value="thibault.fiacre@gmail.com" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="bouton-valider" name="form[submit]" value="Valider" class="bg-info bouton-formulaire btn">Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I execute the test in the console I have this error :

```
1) tests\FormBundle\Controller\FormControllerTest::testReservationAction
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

C:\wamp64\www\tp4_louvres\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler.php:849
C:\wamp64\www\tp4_louvres\tests\FormBundle\Controller\FormControllerTest.php:18
```

It seams like the function `form()` in `$form=$bouton->form();` don't find the form on the page but the button is found...I tried to do `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());`

And I have this error from Symfony :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: 
"Cannot load resource ".". Make sure there is a loader supporting the "extra" type." 
at C:\wamp64\www\tp4_louvres\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader.php line 73
```

I'm lost on this problem for 2 days...if anyone can help me it will be very appreciate ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try adding: `$client->followRedirects(true);`

Comment: Btw. Don't use ids as form field names in `submit()` method, but names, e.g.: `form[jour][jour]`. Here is a working example: https://github.com/djuro/qasite/blob/master/tests/AppBundle/Controller/QuestionControllerTest.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to add `$client->followRedirects(true)` but the issue is always there...I change the ids to the `form[el]` in the `submit()` but nothing change :( The error is always in the line calling the `form()` method, any idea ?

Comment: The `/tp4_louvres/web/app.php/info_reservation` url is not valid. I think that is why the file loader exception. It should be just `info_reservation` . Anyway, find valid url using console: `$ php bin/console debug:router | grep reservation`.

Comment: I am not sure why you use assert to check if it redirected (that url does not look good either). Better check if the destination HTML contains elements that it should have (certain labels or title).

Comment: Thank you for your time ! I found the solution...I used `coresphere_console` in the file `app/config/routing_dev.yml`to use the console on the browser when I put my site online. I just remove this routing from the routing_dev file and now it's working ! Very strange conflict here...I don't understand...But you were right on two points : to change the url to `ìnfo_reservation` which is the correct route and to test if the destination HTML contains elements ! But I don't understand why `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect()`doesn't work...